# Azure IoT Hub is unable to retrieve devices (Shared policy is disabled)

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I created a new resource group as well as a new **IOT hub**.

The next logical step would be to **create a new IoT device** inside the IoT hub.

However the create button in "Explorers/IoT devices" is **disabled** because of the following error message:

> Unable to retrieve devices. Please ensure a Shared access policy is enabled with necessary permissions [Registry Write Service Connect].

**Shared access policies:**

[image]

Comment: Looks like something that's happened recently - this was working before but I got this when I tried today. The solution below worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happened to me to. Check if you are the registered as the owner.

Go to your resource group, "Access Control (IAM)" and click on "Add role assignments". Then select "owner" and add yourself.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable this option you need to set yourself as the hub owner. Go to Access control (IAM) tab and add a role assignment which will grant access to the selected resource. [Grant access tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOCmX.jpg)

Set yourself as a owner and go back to the Explorers => IoT devices view, You can now create a new IoT device.